# Changing a variable inside a function the next time I call it?

Tags: javascript

I am making a chess game. I reached a point where I need to change 4 variables inside a function so the next time I run the function, the variables will be different. Below I have the code necessary to look at:

The function piecesRotation will rotate the position of all the pieces upside down so the other player will play.

Javascript:

```
function piecesRotation(){
    //rotate the pieces
}

function check(el){

    //there variables indicate which user turn is it
    var FirstCurrentPlayersPiece = "B";
    var CurrentPlayersPieceColor = "black";
    var FirstOpponentsPieceLetter = "W";
    var OpponentsPieceColor = "white";
    //If player played then run the function below to change the position of the pieces and change the 4 variables so the other player will play
    piecesRotation();
    FirstCurrentPlayersPiece = "W";
    CurrentPlayersPieceColor = "white";
    FirstOpponentsPieceLetter = "B";
    OpponentsPieceColor = "black";
}
```

On HTML I call the function check(el) where el is the elepemt which the player clicked on.

To illustrate, I need somehow to change these variables:

```
var FirstCurrentPlayersPiece = "B";
var CurrentPlayersPieceColor = "black";
var FirstOpponentsPieceLetter = "W";
var OpponentsPieceColor = "white";
```

To this:

```
var FirstCurrentPlayersPiece = "W";
var CurrentPlayersPieceColor = "white";
var FirstOpponentsPieceLetter = "B";
var OpponentsPieceColor = "black";
```

And the change of these variables will happen each time the player plays. Is there a way to do it?

**IMPORTANT**
*English isn't my first language, that's why I am bad at it.*

**NOTE1**
*The reason I am not providing the whole code is because it's HUGE and Stack overflow doesn't let me paste it.*

**NOTE2**
I am stupid. I had to use global variables (as I think that they are bad practice, it's the only solution.

Comment: declare the variables outside the function so that they retain their values

Comment: The function check(el) is called by the HTML function onClick="check()"

Comment: If you transform your function to  be an object, you can declare variables like `this.OpponentsPieceColor = 'black';`  and change it in any moment with `check.OpponentsPieceColor = 'white';` (change `check` with the variable where your object is instantiated)

Comment: Yes, but how can I call check with HTML (with onClick="check(el)")

Comment: Your question isn't clear. I did try and wirte an answer, but TBH, I stopped as I can't quite figure out what your trying to achive here. this smells of an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Explain your actual issue, not how your trying to solve it currently

Comment: Sorry my English isn't that good. What you don't understand?

Comment: I think he is building a chess/checkers game and is trying to flip the state of the application each time a player makes a move.

Comment: note2 makes no sense, so what if it is called by onclick, they are global variables so they can be accessed in any scope

Answer (score 1):

Just place the variables in an object and pass them to the function

```
var boardState = {
        FirstCurrentPlayersPiece : "B",
        CurrentPlayersPieceColor : "black",
        FirstOpponentsPieceLetter: "W",
        OpponentsPieceColor: "white"
}

function piecesRotation(){       
    boardState =  {
            FirstCurrentPlayersPiece : boardState.FirstOpponentsPieceLetter,
            CurrentPlayersPieceColor : boardState.OpponentsPieceColor,
            FirstOpponentsPieceLetter: boardState.FirstCurrentPlayersPiece,
            OpponentsPieceColor: boardState.CurrentPlayersPieceColor
    }
}


function check(el){
    piecesRotation();
}
```

Comment: Before using your code, can you please explain to me how your code works? (I am asking because I don't want to use a piece of code if I don't understand how it works).

Comment: I placed the variables inside an obejct, and when you call `piecesRotation` and pass along the object it will swap FirstCurrentPlayersPiece and CurrentPlayersPieceColor with FirstOpponentsPieceLetter OpponentsPieceColor and return the modified object. You can then use that modified object to change the state of your application

Comment: I modified the code to use global variables like you are doing. 
You store the board state in a global object and when "check()" is called that object is changed to reflect the new board state.

Comment: Thank you for the info, at the end I used global variables without using object as I don't know much about them. Thank you anyway.